# Difference between "doesn't pity" and "doesn't do pity"?

Tags: sentence-structure

> He doesn’t really do pity.

In a sentence like that one, what's the difference between "doesn't pity" and "doesn't do pity"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb **[pity](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pity)** is transitive: it requires an object:

> I pity **the people who live on the streets**

So, if you want to say that somebody never experiences the feeling of pity, you cannot simply say

> He doesn't pity

It's grammatically incorrect because it lacks an object: you would have to say

> He doesn't pity **anybody or anything**

Alternatively you can use **pity** as a noun:

> He doesn't experience pity

experience is a bit formal, but you can use **do** instead, in the sense **to perform, take part in, or achieve something**

> He doesn't do pity.

The first sentence "he doesn't pity" is grammatically incorrect as it lacks an object: the second sentence "he doesn't do pity" is correct and is currently a fashionable way of expressing ideas of this kind.

Answer (score 2):

In recent years it has become a kind of "hipsterish" thing to say that you `don't do {noun}`. The phrase is deliberately ungrammatical. It labels the {noun} role (broadly construed) as with a rubric and thereby belittles it by turning it into a kind of stereotypical situation. The locution means that you steer well clear of {noun} because your temperament is averse to {noun}.  Doing {noun} is not at all "who you are". You have no inclination whatsoever to be someone who does {noun}.

> I don't do jealous girlfriend.
>
> I don't do pity.
>
> I don't do water-cooler.

If the expression is used of another person:

> He doesn't do pity.

it is an ironic way of saying that it is not in his nature to take pity.

Comment: Can the down-voter please explain the down-vote? ‘Doesn’t pity’ refers only to the one looking on while ‘doesn’t *do* pity’ refers to either party (it’s a rejection of the practice of pitying).

Comment: This seems like a useful answer overall.  The downvote might be because it calls the construction ungrammatical.

Comment: I don't think it's any less grammatical than "I don't do physics". btw, I didn't downvote.

Comment: @JavaLatte: If *I don't do jealous girlfriend* is the same for you as "I don't do physics", that's because "jealous girlfriend" is being *cast* into the role of "defined area of study/activity/endeavor". But it's an "invalid cast" and therein lies the expression of irony. Here's another (famous) invalid cast:  *Anyone lived in a pretty **how** town*.  The invalid casting is what I was referring to when calling the statement "deliberately ungrammatical".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: If there were a cast involved for jealous girlfriends, surely it would be to the performing arts meaning of **do**, like **I don't do drama**?.

Comment: @JavaLatte: *I don't do drama* is analogous to *I don't do physics*, yes. But  **jealous girlfriend** (note the singular) is not an "area of activity" or whatever label you'd want to put on "physics", "drama","math(s)", etc.  Casting "jealous girlfriend" in that way is where the "intentionally invalid" comes into play.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo:***jealous girlfriend - drama** was intended as a joke... you get my upvote anyway for a good explanation of why this kind of expression is fashionable.

Comment: @JavaLatte:  I don't do funny  :)