# meaning of the phrase "do halfway with"

Tags: meaning

I have come across it in this [video](https://youtu.be/3g246c6Bv58). It is at 25 second. Here it is in context:

> Animals come in pretty much every colour, but blue seems to be the rarest. What is cool, though, is when we find blue animals, they are awesome looking. Nature doesn't **do halfway with** blue.

What I can uderstand  is that nature doesn't favour blue, but I cannot quite get the phrase itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **do things halfway** means to leave the job or task unfinished, to fail to do much that was necessary or expected. Compare "to take half measures".

You could say of a person who threw a party, say:

> It was quite a bash, with live music, lots of food, and plenty to drink. Dmytro doesn't do things halfway when throwing a party.

The speaker in your video is then deriving a new phrase from that familiar locution, patterned after another locution. See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/162940/difference-between-doesnt-pity-and-doesnt-do-pity/162968#162968).  Only here, it would be **do** + preposition or **do** + adverb (depending on how you analyze "halfway").

**Nature doesn't do halfway** is like saying of a guy who always drives his car too fast:

> He doesn't do "slow".

And **with** means "with respect to, regarding,  involving".

With regard to blue (creatures), it is not in Nature's nature to do anything other than a bang-up job.